# In Winforms how to reload/reinitialize a user control from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a form called `WindowMain` which is the main window of my project. This form has a panel that displays a user control called `UserControlRoster` whenever the "Roster" button is clicked on the main window.

This `UserControlRoster` has a datagridview that displays a list of people (or 'roster') as well as a number of labels (Name, Age, etc) which get filled with each persons corresponding data whenever they're selected in the datagridiew.

When the user clicks the `Name` label on this `UserControlRoster`, a dialog form is displayed allowing them to change that persons name. This works fine however once they click "Save", I need the `UserControlRoster` to completely re load or re-initialize in order for the changes to the name to take effect.

I guess to put it simply, what I'm asking is: how do I go about re-loading or re-initilizing a user control that is displayed on a form, by another form? I am very lost so any help would be much appreciated!

When the user clicks the `Roster` button on the main form the `Roster` user control gets added to the panel.

```
MainScreenPanel.Controls.Clear();
var uc = new UserControlRoster() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
MainScreenPanel.Controls.Add(uc);
```

When the user clicks the persons name label on the user control it opens the "Edit Wrestler Name" form:

```
wrestlerName = lblName.Text.ToString();

DialogEditWrestlerName EditWrestlerName = new DialogEditWrestlerName(wrestlerName);
EditWrestlerName.Show();
```

On the "Edit Wrestler Name" form, when the user clicks save, this form gets closed and the Main Window gets opened again. This is obviously incorrect.

```
WindowMain Main = new WindowMain();
Main.Show(this);
this.Close();
```

Comment: I would call the edit dialog using `.ShowDialog()` as opposed to `.Show()` you can then check the return the value of this method to ensure the dialog was closed as expected (you may need to set DialogResult property on your Save button) and then call your `PopulateData` method which I assume you have, but is not shown. Do not create a new instance of main within the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, since the secondary form is dismissed, switch to `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. The code in the main form STOPS until the "dialog" is dismissed:

```
// in the main form:
wrestlerName = lblName.Text.ToString();

DialogEditWrestlerName EditWrestlerName = new DialogEditWrestlerName(wrestlerName);
EditWrestlerName.ShowDialog(); // code STOPS here until "EditWrestlerName" is dismissed
// Here you can directly update the control,
// since the main form has access to it
```

If the secondary form has a "cancel" option, then you  might want to check the return of `ShowDialog()` instead:

```
// in the main form:
wrestlerName = lblName.Text.ToString();

DialogEditWrestlerName EditWrestlerName = new DialogEditWrestlerName(wrestlerName);
if (EditWrestlerName.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { // code STOPS here until "EditWrestlerName" is dismissed
    // Here you can directly update the control,
    // since the main form has access to it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have since modified the code. However the UserControlRoster still is not updated to show the changed name once the DialogEditWrestlerName is closed.

Comment: Well, how did you "update" the control in the spot where I have comments indicating you can do the update?...

Comment: I didn't as I'm not sure how to do this, hence this post.

Comment: Okay. You said that "This UserControlRoster has a datagridview that displays a list of people". How did you populate the DataGridView in the first place?